# Using the Image() Object with video in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I was wondering about the Image object. Is it possible to use it with a video file as the src? Currently, I get this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type video/mpeg
```

Is there a working way to do this? Or is there some other object I can use/make to replace the Image object?
(This is on a file called test.mjpeg, a short video w/o audio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, Image() is purely for images. For video you'll either need to go with Flash or check out the <video> tag.

Comment: Is there any Video() equivalent implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure. You might be able to just get the <video> tag with getElementById() or whatever your JS library uses, and setting the src attribute manually.